# What's semantically correct here - a <table> or a <ul>?

Tags: html, html-lists, html-table, semantic-markup

Let's assume you have an overview like this:

[image: Post Overview Example]

To me, this is both a table *and* a couple of nested lists.

**What is the semantically correct way of implementing this in HTML?**

Comment: dl + dt + dd for a list  . nested list do fine here

Comment: A list of lists. That's actually possible.

Comment: I'd say this is a series of tuples so a dl would be in order. This isn't really tabular data as the columns aren't a series, other than the dates.

Comment: It is much more useful to consider how it should be navigated and rendered. “Semantics” is just play with words when discussing HTML. The `table` and `ul` elements do not have any real *meanings* (which is what real semantics would be about); they are just data structures.

Comment: Would the one voting to close this question, **please** leave a comment as to why?

Comment: this is entirely subjective, as there is no way to quantify any of it. i love semantics, and i've participated before in these, but there is no winner. and i didn't vote to close, anon trolls run amok here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968462/mike), I don't think we're dealing with tabular data here. You have nested *lists* of publications. Following a few guidelines ([Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1408986), [html5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/time-and-data-element/), ...) about authorship and publications dates; the extra data about publication you're dealing with is more likely "*labels*" to your content that could be styled in many ways, thus rejecting the tabular data hypothesis. I've chosen the following approach per `<li>` :

```
<span class="title">What Should I use, li or table?</span>        
<time datetime="2014-04-08T15:27Z">2d ago</time>
<address><a rel="author" href="#">John Jackson</a></address>
```

I reproduced your nested *list* in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yPcx/), [styled **it**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yPcx/1/) as yours and [styled **it**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yPcx/3/) in a non-tabular way. You'll notice the HTML segment never changed in any of the three styling I've produced. Being able to style it like the previous Fiddles demonstrates how the **HTML** is **semantically appropriate**.

Semantics often induces different valid approaches, some of my usage might not be perfect, but the main idea should be appropriate. Let me know if this answers your question properly! :-)

Comment: Thank you! I've come to the same conclusion as one comment above, that is, that it's probably entirely subjective and both approaches work. But your examples are really nice and helpful, so I accept your answer.

Comment: Just one follow-up question: In your [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8yPcx/1/), what's the correct way to introduce and style headers ("Post", "User", "Date") and make them line up with the actual data as you would have in a table?

Comment: Ha! This sounds more like the job for a `table` markup. If you actually need headers to represent not-so-obvious-data, your data is probably more fit as a `table` governed by `th` headers. While semantics is studied to have the content express it's purpose by itself; I'm pretty sure headers, in your example, wouldn't add any value to the explication of data. Your content's purpose is clear in the two styling I proposed *and* in *pure* **HTML**. If you need headers, you should use a table. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the others are being thrown off by the bullets. This contains tabular data, so a **table** is fitting. The list-like styling can be easily created within table cells.

It seems to me, however, that the representation of data is entirely as a table, and the list-like structure is just to show the structure of messages (ie, by indenting replies).

Comment: It's not tabular data, the nesting is the important thing which makes it perfect for a list.  The only thing tabular about it is the name and date, but that's just labeling each list element.  The main structure is the nesting of the threads and responses.  Bullets have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a nested list.  The first one is the outermost, with three items under it, some of which have lists of their own.

Essentially it could look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>What Should I use
    <ul>
      <li>Re: What Should I use </li>
      <li>I think the best option is . . .
        <ul> . . . </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To get the name and date info lined up you could probably use a `float: right` span element, and to prevent the `li` from wrapping you'd probably need to set overflow appropriately, but I think it's just a matter of formatting.

Comment: What about the information about the author and when the post was created? Isn't that - together with the post title - tabular information?

Comment: No, that's a matter of formatting.  The info isn't tabular, it's just that you want it lined up a certain way.  Probably floating right would work for that.